# What's SFTP utility? How can I get it & use it to upload images by CSV file?

Tags: import, image, csv, media

**What's SFTP utility? 
How can I get it & use it to upload images by CSV file?**

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh that's not really relevant, because the question has not much to do with Magento itself. As I understand it, OP asks for a tool to upload images for import via SFTP.

Comment: That being said @Radwa, it depends on your operating system. Google for "MacOS SFTP" or "Windows SFTP" and you will find what you need.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is 1. a shopping question and 2. not related to the Magento platform